# How to fetch data generated on pc to web server

Tags: php

I am working on a project that generates data on pc (with c++) and then has to send it to http server (that is being ran on xampp right now). Generated data has to be sent every 1 millisecond (that is a requirement) and then being streamed to users on the http server mentioned above. I could not find the right way to do it.

So far I have tried:

- Sending a get request from c++ to web server file named 'data_receiver.php' which then saves it to a file (file.txt). Another file named 'data_fetcher.php' (site that users go to and read outputed data) runs ajax call (every 1 millisecond) to 'data_reader_ajax.php' which grabs data from 'file.txt' and echoes it to a callback. After receiving callback, 'data_fetcher.php' reads received data and fetches it to the page.

Using this method costs ~50 ms + a traffic in a browser appears that messes things up (usually crashes browser).

```
$json_data =  json_decode(file_get_contents("json-data.txt"));

$player_array = $json_data->players;

$player_exist = false;

foreach($player_array as $key=>$item)
{
    if($item->id == $_GET["id"])
    {
        $player_array[$key] = $player_object;
        $player_exists = true;
    }
}

if($player_exists == false)
{
    array_push($player_array, $player_object);

}

$json_data->players = $player_array;

$fp = fopen("json-data.txt","wb");
fwrite($fp,json_encode($json_data));
fclose($fp);
```

- Identical to the first method, but using mysql server to store data this time.

This costs 50 - 500 ms + similar traffic appears (although, this time it doesn't crash the browser).

```
$db_handle = new DBController;

$json_data = json_decode($db_handle->runQuery("SELECT * FROM player_json")[0]["player_json"]);


$player_exists = false;

if($json_data != "")
{       
    $player_array = $json_data->players;

    foreach($player_array as $key=>$item)
    {
        if($item->id == $_GET["id"])
        {
            $player_array[$key] = $player_object;
            $player_exists = true;
        }
    }

    if($player_exists == false)
    {
        array_push($player_array, $player_object);
    }

    $json_data->players = $player_array;

    $db_handle->insert("UPDATE player_json SET player_json = '" . json_encode($json_data) . "'");

} else {
    $json_data = (object) array("players" => [], "entities" => [ (object) array("hello"=>"hello"), (object) array("hello"=>"hello")]);

    $player_array = $json_data->players;

    array_push($player_array, $player_object);

    $json_data->players = $player_array;

    $db_handle->insert("UPDATE player_json SET player_json = '" . json_encode($json_data) . "'");
}
```

- 3rd method (which was the most efficient, but not really) was storing data to php $_SESSION["data"].

This method saved data every in 0.3 millisecond while testing it with a GET link which contained $_GET request elements. Soon I realized, that it would work only if user kept spamming the link and only on a single browser. I felt stupid after realizing that.

```
if(isset($_SESSION["json_data"]))
{    
    $json_data = $_SESSION["json_data"];

    $player_array = $json_data->players;

    if($player_exists == false)
    {
        array_push($player_array, $player_object);
    }

    $_SESSION["json_data"]->players = $player_array;

} else {
    $_SESSION["json_data"] = (object) array("players" => [], "entities" => [ (object) array("hello"=>"hello"), (object) array("hello"=>"hello")]);

    $json_data = $_SESSION["json_data"];

    $player_array = $json_data->players;

    array_push($player_array, $player_object);
}
```

($player_object is object that is being generated after reading GET)
(Players with the same id are being updated. With new id - pushed into the array)

What other options do I have? I need to make the site as fast and as accurate as possible. (It's not necessary to use apache server nor to program in PHP, I just need a site where all data gets outputted)
(Only one person will be running a site with displayed data).

*IMPORTANT*: I can not modify c++ (unless it's only slightly different data sending method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look at an in-memory cache such as [Redis](https://redis.io/).
C++ -> Redis <- PHP

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will check it out. Although, do you have any speculation of how fast it is going to process the data as in my case?

Comment: It will be greater than 1ms.